# как отличить проект каторый создан с помошю CRA(Create React App) от того что написан руками

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

и еше вопрос, можно ли создать через CRA и добавить свои webpack config-и, не трогая то что есть в CRA(то есть без eject команды)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации `react-scripts` это пакет, который включает скрипты и конфигурации для `create-react-app`

Посмотрите в файл `package.json` в корне проекта.

Если там есть пакет [`react-scripts`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/react-scripts) значит проект создан через команду `create-react-app`.

> и еше вопрос, можно ли создать через CRA и добавить свои webpack config-и, не трогая то что есть в CRA(то есть без eject команды)

Да, можно, но только используя другие библиотеки.

[**react-app-rewired**](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired)

[**customize-cra**](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra)

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Armen рад помочь